Tangents to ellipse intersecting with reciprocal slope
Given an ellipse $x^2 / a^2 + y^2/b^2 = 1$ where $a \ne b$, find the equation of the set of all points from which there are two tangents to the curve whose slopes are reciprocals.
Now if $(x_1, y_1)$ is the point on this ellipse, then I could use some Calculus to arrive at the following equation of the tangent at this point
$$ b^2 x_1 x + a^2 y_1 y = a^2 b^2 $$
Slope of this tangent is $\left( -b^2 x_1 / a^2 y_1 \right)$. So, slope of the tangent with the reciprocal is $ \left( - a^2 y_1 / b^2 x_1 \right) $. But I am stuck here.

Hint:
From here ,
the equations of the pair of tangent from $(h,k)$ is $$m^2(h^2-a^2)-2khm+k^2-b^2=0$$ where is the gradient.
If $m_1,m_2$ are the two values of the quadratic equation,  $$m_1m_2=\dfrac{k^2-b^2}{h^2-a^2}$$
But from the given condition, $m_1m_2=1$
Can you take it home from here?

Take a point $(\alpha,\beta)$ of that ellipse. If $(\gamma,\delta)$ also belongs to the ellipse, then the tangent lines to the ellipse at $(\alpha,\beta)$ and $(\gamma,\delta)$ shall be orthogonal if and only if the normal lines at those points are orthogonal. But the direction of the normal lines is given by the gradient. So, you get the condition$$\left(2\frac\alpha{a^2},2\frac\beta{b^2}\right).\left(2\frac\gamma{a^2},2\frac\delta{b^2}\right)=0,$$which is equivalent to $\frac{\alpha\gamma}{a^4}+\frac{\gamma\delta}{b^4}=0$. Therefore, you have three relations:$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}\frac{\alpha^2}{a^2}+\frac{\beta^2}{b^2}=1\\\frac{\gamma^2}{a^2}+\frac{\delta^2}{b^2}=1\\\frac{\alpha\gamma}{a^4}+\frac{\beta\delta}{b^4}=0.\end{array}\right.$$This leads to:$$(\gamma,\delta)=\frac{\pm1}{\sqrt{a^6\beta^2+b^6\alpha^2}}\left(-a^4\beta,b^4\alpha\right).$$
